# UWP Virtual Smart Card sample c# - exception

Tags: uwp, smartcard

I am currently trying to get the Smart Card C# example (can be found here--> https://  github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmartCard/cs) running on my Win10 client (user is in local admin group), but unfortunately it is not working....

Example:

Creating a TPM Virtual Smartcard works perfectly with the cmd line (as administrator):

**TpmVscMgr create /name MyVSC /pin default /adminkey random /generate**

Creating a TPM Virtual Smartcard DOES NOT work when running cmd line NOT as administrator:
UAC opens--> "*Requested operation requires elevation*" - which is the behavior I was expecting...

Running the provided Smart Card C# sample which contains in fact the code from here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/smart-cards) is not working....the error message/exception shows: "*The requested operation requires elevation*" when trying to create a TPM Virtual Smart Card.

As far as I know it is not possible to start a UWP as an administrator....please correct me if I am wrong...

Questions:

What am I missing here? It seems that there is a correlation between the behavior of the two described Szenarios... I do not think that is possible to create a VSC without admin privileges but it is in fact quite funny that Microsoft offers a  Smartcard API that should be able to do this! Probably anyone of you guys have experience with programmatically creating virtual smartcards and help me!?

[image: Screenshot of the sample including the exception]